# Slick: Model Option[(col1, col2)], so that both are missing or both defined

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table multiple `Option[X]` columns. I want to model the fact that for these columns, either *all* are defined or *all* are missing. How to do this, given that columns are defined as individual `Option[X]`?

```
def startDate = column[Option[LocalDate]]("start_date", O.Default(None))

def endDate = column[Option[LocalDate]]("end_date", O.Default(None))

def dateRange: Rep[Option[(LocalDate,LocalDate)]] = ??? // How to make something like this?
```

Comment: Instead of bending over backwards to feed the Slick beast, I suggest just fetching whatever is convenient to fetch and then just parsing the output - there is no law saying that you cannot just get a tuple of values and map it to ADT yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest mappings when building up a projection with Slick. That is, you can define `*` to include other `mapTo` (for a case class) or `<>` calls (for a custom mapping).

Using an example with `Int` rather than `LocalDate`,
we can start with the case class we want to work with:

```
case class Row(
  name  : String,
  range : Option[(Int, Int)],
  id    : Long = 0L
)
```

Notice the `range` field is made a single value (tuple), but in the database we can represent this as two columns called `start` and `end`:

```
class RowTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Row](tag, "row") {
  def id    = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name  = column[String]("name")
  def start = column[Option[Int]]("start")
  def end   = column[Option[Int]]("end")

  def range = (start, end) <> (into_range, from_range)

  def * = (name, range, id).mapTo[Row]
}
```

The `*` projection into a `Row` is built up from another mapping I've called `range`.

The `range` mapping is on the two columns `start` and `end`. What we provide to `<>` is two functions: one function converts a pair of options into the type we want (an option of a tuple); the other function goes the other way. The functions mirror the standard library functions `tupled` and `unappy` (`unapply` is an [extractor](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/extractors.html#24.2)).

We can write those functions however we want, and I've written them out with pattern matching:

```
def into_range(pair: (Option[Int], Option[Int])): Option[(Int, Int)] =
  pair match {
    case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some((x, y))
    case _                  => None
  }

def from_range(r: Option[(Int, Int)]): Option[(Option[Int], Option[Int])] =
  r match {
     case Some((x, y)) => Some((Some(x), Some(y)))
     case _            => Some((None, None))
  }
```

In summary, your `dateRange` is equivelent to the `range` mapping in this example, but rather than call it directly we include it inside our default projection, `*`.